# How can I enable fullscreen in Flowplayer 5.2 that's in an iframe?

Tags: iframe, fullscreen, flowplayer

I'm building an embeddable player with flowplayer 5.2 and noticed that fullscreen support is gone when it's in an `iframe`. Those other big players have `allowFullScreen` in their iframe code but the flowplayer script doesn't see it or I don't know how to make it see it.
Has anyone here figured this out?
Thanks,
thomas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. flowplayer sets `window == window.top` as default for fullscreen so in order to make it work you need to manually set `flowplayer.conf.fullscreen = true;`