# Flowplayer 5.3.2 fullscreen button missing in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, fullscreen, flowplayer

I have .mp4 videos that I would like to stream using Flowplayer.  It works great, but when I put it in an iframe, the fullscreen button is missing.

This question was answered by someone here: [How can I enable fullscreen in Flowplayer 5.2 that's in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799804/how-can-i-enable-fullscreen-in-flowplayer-5-2-thats-in-an-iframe)

But I can't figure out where to put the `flowplayer.conf.fullscreen = true;`

Here's my index.html code so far:

```
<head>
</style>

   <!-- player skin -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skin/minimalist.css" />

   <!-- site specific styling -->
   <style>
     body { text-align: center; padding-top: 5%; }
     .flowplayer { width: 80%; background-color: green;}
   </style>

   <!-- flowplayer depends on jQuery 1.7.1+ (for now) -->
   <!-- leave out http/https from the src to fix issue with controls not loading in Chrome -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <!-- include flowplayer -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

   <!-- the player -->
   <div class="flowplayer" data-swf="flowplayer.swf" >
      <video>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="myvid.mp4"/>
      </video>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

These should be set right after Flowplayer has been included in your page (with script src).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/5.3.2/flowplayer.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
flowplayer.conf.embed = false;
flowplayer.conf.fullscreen = true;
</script>
```

This link http://flowplayer.org/docs/#global-configuration explains more on this

Answer (score 0):

Try manually initializing flowplayer with `$(".player").flowplayer({ swf: "/path/to/flowplayer.swf" });`